# Can energy increase during neuron dynamics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Consider a system of Ising spins, with Hamiltonian:

$$H(\mathbf{S})=-\sum_{i, j} J_{i j} S_{i} S_{j} \qquad (1)$$

where $J_{ij}$ are symmetric real couplings ($J_{ij}=J_{ji}$) and $S_i=\pm1$.

Consider a time dynamics with the following parallel update rule:

$$S_{i}(t+1)=\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sum_{j} J_{i j} S_{j}(t)-\theta_{i}\right) \qquad (2)$$

where $\theta_i$ is a fixed real number (the threshold for neuron $i$).

This model is taken from the first pages of the book by Engel and Broeck, *Statistical Mechanics of Learning* (2001), Equations 1.1 and 1.2.

There it is claimed that following the dynamics (2), the energy (1) can never increase.

But consider the example where $\theta_i$ is very large for all $i$.  Then $S_i(t+1)=-1$ for all $i$, regardless of the values of $\mathbf S(t)$. It then follows that $H(\mathbf S(t+1))=-\sum_{ij}J_{ij}$, which need not be smaller or equal than $H(\mathbf S(t+1))$.

Am I missing something here, or is the statement in the book plainly wrong? Maybe it can be proved at least for $\theta_i=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bias term $\theta_i$ should be represented in the Hamiltonian: $$H(S)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}J_{ij}S_iS_j + \sum_i \theta_i S_i$$
(The half factor is standard in the neural network literature, not sure if it is needed here). This is the form used for Hopfield networks.

If one neuron flips as $S_i'=\text{sgn}\left(\sum_j J_{ij}S_j - \theta_i\right)$ then $\Delta H = -(\sum_{j} J_{ij}S_j)(S_i'-S_i) + \theta_i (S_i' - S_i) = ( -\sum_{j} J_{ij}S_j + \theta_i)(S_i'-S_i)$. The first factor has the opposite sign as $S_i'$. If $S_i'>0$ then the first factor is negative and the second positive, so the energy decreases. If it is negative, then the first factor is positive and the second factor is negative, so energy decreases.

[In the synchronous case](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-26-22-4808) where all neurons update simultaneously energy can increase (leading to oscillatory behaviour) if the $J_{ii}$ autoconnections are zero, or remain stable but flip between same energy states.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I guess the authors forgot including $\theta_i$ in the Hamiltonian. However, I think your proof applies only if the update is sequential. What about parallel updates?

Comment: @becko - Thanks. Yes, this is the asynchronous case. Will update with the synchronous case where there is weaker guarantees.

Comment: Ok. So definitely the book has a few errors here and the question is not as simple as it looks. Thanks for clearing it up.